# Why computing the distance between two ellipsoidal coordinates needs to be iterative?

Tags: distance, spherical-geometry, ellipsoid

I have found internal Android code that calculates distance between two spheroidal coordinates. It is complex and it is iterative. Why? Can't this calculation be done in "single shot"?

The Java code below:

```
private static void computeDistanceAndBearing(double lat1, double lon1,
    double lat2, double lon2, float[] results) {
    // Based on http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf
    // using the "Inverse Formula" (section 4)

    int MAXITERS = 20;
    // Convert lat/long to radians
    lat1 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
    lat2 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
    lon1 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
    lon2 *= Math.PI / 180.0;

    double a = 6378137.0; // WGS84 major axis
    double b = 6356752.3142; // WGS84 semi-major axis
    double f = (a - b) / a;
    double aSqMinusBSqOverBSq = (a * a - b * b) / (b * b);

    double L = lon2 - lon1;
    double A = 0.0;
    double U1 = Math.atan((1.0 - f) * Math.tan(lat1));
    double U2 = Math.atan((1.0 - f) * Math.tan(lat2));

    double cosU1 = Math.cos(U1);
    double cosU2 = Math.cos(U2);
    double sinU1 = Math.sin(U1);
    double sinU2 = Math.sin(U2);
    double cosU1cosU2 = cosU1 * cosU2;
    double sinU1sinU2 = sinU1 * sinU2;

    double sigma = 0.0;
    double deltaSigma = 0.0;
    double cosSqAlpha = 0.0;
    double cos2SM = 0.0;
    double cosSigma = 0.0;
    double sinSigma = 0.0;
    double cosLambda = 0.0;
    double sinLambda = 0.0;

    double lambda = L; // initial guess
    for (int iter = 0; iter < MAXITERS; iter++) {
        double lambdaOrig = lambda;
        cosLambda = Math.cos(lambda);
        sinLambda = Math.sin(lambda);
        double t1 = cosU2 * sinLambda;
        double t2 = cosU1 * sinU2 - sinU1 * cosU2 * cosLambda;
        double sinSqSigma = t1 * t1 + t2 * t2; // (14)
        sinSigma = Math.sqrt(sinSqSigma);
        cosSigma = sinU1sinU2 + cosU1cosU2 * cosLambda; // (15)
        sigma = Math.atan2(sinSigma, cosSigma); // (16)
        double sinAlpha = (sinSigma == 0) ? 0.0 :
            cosU1cosU2 * sinLambda / sinSigma; // (17)
        cosSqAlpha = 1.0 - sinAlpha * sinAlpha;
        cos2SM = (cosSqAlpha == 0) ? 0.0 :
            cosSigma - 2.0 * sinU1sinU2 / cosSqAlpha; // (18)

        double uSquared = cosSqAlpha * aSqMinusBSqOverBSq; // defn
        A = 1 + (uSquared / 16384.0) * // (3)
            (4096.0 + uSquared *
             (-768 + uSquared * (320.0 - 175.0 * uSquared)));
        double B = (uSquared / 1024.0) * // (4)
            (256.0 + uSquared *
             (-128.0 + uSquared * (74.0 - 47.0 * uSquared)));
        double C = (f / 16.0) *
            cosSqAlpha *
            (4.0 + f * (4.0 - 3.0 * cosSqAlpha)); // (10)
        double cos2SMSq = cos2SM * cos2SM;
        deltaSigma = B * sinSigma * // (6)
            (cos2SM + (B / 4.0) *
             (cosSigma * (-1.0 + 2.0 * cos2SMSq) -
              (B / 6.0) * cos2SM *
              (-3.0 + 4.0 * sinSigma * sinSigma) *
              (-3.0 + 4.0 * cos2SMSq)));

        lambda = L +
            (1.0 - C) * f * sinAlpha *
            (sigma + C * sinSigma *
             (cos2SM + C * cosSigma *
              (-1.0 + 2.0 * cos2SM * cos2SM))); // (11)

        double delta = (lambda - lambdaOrig) / lambda;
        if (Math.abs(delta) < 1.0e-12) {
            break;
        }
    }

    float distance = (float) (b * A * (sigma - deltaSigma));
    results[0] = distance;
    if (results.length > 1) {
        float initialBearing = (float) Math.atan2(cosU2 * sinLambda,
            cosU1 * sinU2 - sinU1 * cosU2 * cosLambda);
        initialBearing *= 180.0 / Math.PI;
        results[1] = initialBearing;
        if (results.length > 2) {
            float finalBearing = (float) Math.atan2(cosU1 * sinLambda,
                -sinU1 * cosU2 + cosU1 * sinU2 * cosLambda);
            finalBearing *= 180.0 / Math.PI;
            results[2] = finalBearing;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the formula in not only for computing great circle distance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance but also for solving the path between the points https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_navigation.

Comment: So, being a complete layman on the subject... Finding the great circle means finding the right angle of the arc between two points on a sphere (earth here)? And unlike would be thought - It cannot be calculated by a formula, but only using recursive calculation?

Comment: Finding the the distance on a spheroid is a *partial differential equation*. It can only be solved by iterative means.

Comment: Okay.. Thinking of it, in terms of geometry it's dead simple to find the right arc angles: pull a straight line between the points and draw a "ray" from the shpere center through that line - the arc drawn by the ray on the sphere surface is the shortest big circle distance. But I guess, as said, calculating the distance is something else...

Comment: No, both [geodetic problems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy) are *hard* on a spheroid.

Comment: spheroid is also known as ellipsoid, a oblate sphere. You're right about math on a sphere, but look up [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic). Working on a shape that more closely approximate the "true" shape of the Earth is more difficult.

Comment: So it's the fact that earth is a slightly eliptic/deformed shpere makes the computation complex?

Comment: It's the fact that this algorithm is based on the assumption of a spheroidal/ellipsoidal (rather than a simple sphere) model of the Earth. (Yes, it's a better fit to the Earth's "true" shape.)

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comments on the question to an answer:

It is the slightly deformed shpere shape of the earth (a spheroidal/ellipsoidal and not a perfect shpere) that requires a more complex algorithm to calculate distances from point A to point B on a map.